# Can an SBT plugin embed tasks from another plugin?

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

I've created a plugin that generates some web resources that need to be compiled using the `sbt-webpack` plugin. Ideally my plugin would just have a task `bundle` that will `generate` some resources and then it will bundle them with the `webpack` task from the `sbt-webpack` plugin.

What is the right way to incorporate tasks from different plugins into the code defining my tasks in my plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a dependency on another plugin should be enough. You need to add this line to your auto-plugin:

```scala
override def requires = stejskal.sbt.WebpackPlugin
```

This will ensure that sbt-webpack is enabled whenever your plugins is and its settings will be loaded before the ones you define in your plugin. Plus whatever keys sbt-webpack adds to its `autoImport` object will be available to the users of your plugin as well.